# WordPress, Show a post based on highest comments

Tags: php, wordpress, comments, posts

Would anyone know how to make a post show based on highest commented?

Maybe someone has done it already?

Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi you can add this from admin  check this screen shot http://prnt.sc/bpcs98
or for more detail check this video tutorial http://www.wpbeginner.com/plugins/how-to-display-most-commented-posts-in-your-wordpress-sidebar/

Comment: I looked at it before but did not explore it in depth, thanks.!